# Typecast to String from Any got crash

Tags: swift, casting, objectmapper

I have a code to sort array of object MyDate, which since is Any, and the value is set from ObjectMapper, the value of since get from json like this:

```
... 
"since": "1536642141",
...
```

Those code run well in Xcode 9.4.1 but got crash in Xcode 10.

```
tempDates = tempDates.sorted(by: { Int(String.init(describing: $0.since))! < Int(String.init(describing: $1.since))!  })
```

The crash message is "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" 
Is this a bug of Xcode? How could I fix it?

Comment: Why is `since` type `Any`? Why not make it a `String`?

Comment: It strongly depends on other parts of your code, when you get some runtime error on a line. Please try to show all relevant code, simplified but enough to reproduce your issue, is preferred.

Comment: @AshleyMills it should be Int or Double, it's a timestamp (September 11, 2018 5:02:21 AM)

Comment: Yes, that's true - seems like their webservice needs work though as it's returning a string!

Comment: I can't set since to String, because sometimes it return Int, in some other case it is "since": 1536642141

Answer (score -1):

There can be three reasons for Int to return nil when initialized with a random string.

1. When string has digits greater than 32-bit/64-bit length
   `let a = Int(String.init(describing: "153664214187878888878878"))`
2. When string does not contain any digits
   `let a = Int(String.init(describing: "heyyowhynodigits"))`
3. When string has other characters with digits
   `let a = Int(String.init(describing: "heyyowhynodigits"))`

These reasons should be valid for both XCode 9.4.1 and XCode 10. 
It is possible though, that on XCode 9.4.1, a 64-bit length string was tested on a 64-bit length device/emulator. 

But, in case of XCode 10, the testing is being done a 32-bit device/simulator, making case 1(above) valid.